Google Workspace add on attempting to authenticate as users personal account instead of work account
We have a situation where users are logged into both work and personal accounts and do not want to log out of their personal accounts to use our add on.
How can we force the ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() call to use the work account instead of the personal account?
Below you can see I am logged in as a work account on the icognition.cloud domain, yet the App Script attempts to authorize as my personal account.

Here is a way to reproduce the issue:
// call this from anywhere while logged in as two accounts, theres no way to tell it to retrieve a token for a particular account
ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();


Handling multiple logins is a long running issue that devs have no control over. The best you can do is ask your users to leverage separate Chrome profiles for each account they own.

[Edit] to show your code as [mcve] including any url redirects.

// call this from anywhere while logged ... for a particular account That's not how this works. This looks to be a side panel. So, I assume that this is bound to a sheet or document and that this is activated by a menu(BTW, I don't have to assume, all this should've been in your question. )  Once  you click the menu item, script runs with the currently logged in account(work account only). Which account did you use to authorize the script? That account will be the running account. But, I assume you're using oauth token to access resources which  do not support oauth method.

Any way, your question lacks too much information to give an adequate answer.

@TheMaster I can reproduce the issue anywhere that appscript code can be run from by executing ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(), it always attempts to use the personal account if the user is signed in with both a work and personal account. "Once you click the menu item, script runs with the currently logged in account(work account only)." This isn't true.

What's the logged output of console.log(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail())?

@TheMaster thats the correct email, I've discovered some strange behavior that makes me think this has nothing to do with ScriptApp I'll delete this and ask a seperate question

So, I was right. Since this question has no answer, and has an active bounty, rather [edit] it to provide [mcve].

From the question

How can we force the ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() call to use the work account instead of the personal account?

Set the work account as the default account. To do this, users should sign out. Then, they should sign in using the work account first and then the personal account.

Too complicated for my users, Google really needs to improve the behavior for work/personal accounts
